# How can I compile "Triangle" using makefiles on a Windows machine

Tags: makefile

I have just discovered a mesh generator called triangle, found here http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html

I am having some issues building this using the make files that are provided. When I passed in the makefile to my visual studio via the command prompt, I got an error

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 11.00.50727.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make './triangle.c'
Stop.
```

I have no idea how to debug this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eh? Did you read the copious comments in `makefile`? Just remove `-DLINUX` from `CSWITCHES`. Do not try to build `showme`. Use gcc.

So, with cygwin installed (don't forget the *make* and *gcc* packages):

```
C> bash --login
$ vim makefile
```

Remove `-DLINUX`, then

```
$ make triangle
cc -O -I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -o ./triangle ./triangle.c -lm
$ make tricall
cc -O -I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -DTRILIBRARY -c -o ./triangle.o \
    ./triangle.c
cc -O -I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -o ./tricall ./tricall.c \
    ./triangle.o -lm
$ ./triangle.exe
triangle [-prq__a__uAcDjevngBPNEIOXzo_YS__iFlsCQVh] input_file
    -p  Triangulates a Planar Straight Line Graph (.poly file).
    -r  Refines a previously generated mesh.
    ...
```

Easy, no?

Answer (score 0):

That is a makefile.  `nmake` is not actually a make program, or to be clear, it doesn't conform to the POSIX definition of make.  It can't be used with this makefile.  Assuming you don't want to go find a POSIX-based system (GNU/Linux, Mac OSX, Solaris, etc.) to work with this on, you'll need to either (a) compile it by hand (it doesn't look like there are too many files) or (b) get a copy of make for your Windows system.  There are various ports of GNU make for Windows; probably the easiest one for you to get is from MinGW: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Extension/make/make-3.82-mingw32/

Comment: I just get a whole lot of compiler errors - I've been up all night trying to figure this out. I downloaded the source from the file and tried to build it and it just doesn't work. Why don't these things ever work? Every time I see "compile your own", I just die a little inside because I know I'll be up a few hours extra that night trying to figure out what I am actually supposed to do.

Comment: PS: No hate on you, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I am just frustrated at the situation! Every time I have a source file at hand, I can never get it to 'just work;'

Comment: They don't work because you're not using a UNIX-based system.  For many reasons, the free/open source environment has flourished around these types of systems.  Most free software is written to work on UNIX systems, like GNU/Linux, and no consideration has been given to Windows builds.  It's too strange, different, and difficult to support Windows.  Their C compiler does not even conform to the C99 standard for heaven's sake!  Who has the time or energy to deal with it, if they're not getting paid?  Anyway, that's MHO.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling this on windows is gonna make your head sore... It's not portable. I think I saw a few Linux Syscalls in there.

So like the previous answer said, either install a Linux distribution or get yourself MiniGW or CygWin - My Personal favorite.

Comment: I have minigw (and now cygwin) and cant get either of them to work. when I point them to the make file i get compile errors

Comment: @Prodigga give us some output? This doesn't look like a makefile problem

Answer (score 0):

I agree with getack that building on Windows in general is a recipe for headaches. But [triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) by Jonathan Richard Shewchuk is (an awesome) single-file program with no dependencies, so in this case you are fine:

**1)** Install the [microsoft SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) (it's free for the command line stuff).

**2)** Then create the following file `build.bat` in the folder with the unpacked source files:

```
REM Compile Triangle using Microsoft C compiler
REM You must install the msvc SDK
REM Janus, 2013

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd"
cl /DNO_TIMER /DCPU86 triangle.c
```

**3)** Run the `build.bat` file. This should create a nice `triangle.exe`.

**Background**: The call to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd` is required to set up the environment for the microsoft build system. Alternatively the SDK installs a *Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt* where `SetEnv` is run. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660764%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Janus answer worked for after some work. If you are having issues using the bat file he wrote, open SetEnv.cmd (Paste C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd in any file-browser / cmd and hit enter). Then navigate to the project with "cd Path". Than type "cl /DNO_TIMER /DCPU86 triangle.c". Basically its the bat file executed manually. (The bat didnt work for me)